# How to get salesforce Sessionid without passing username& password?

Tags: java, oauth, salesforce, sessionid

How to get salesforce **sessionId** from Java without passing username and password? Is it possible to do it using OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [JWT OAuth](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) flow, in this flow you use a signed JWT to authenticate.